# Customisable Progress Bar in Html/CSS

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I want to create a progress bar like below, using HTML and CSS. Getting no idea as to how to do it. Any help?

[image: progress-bar.png]

Comment: are you using Bootstrap or anything like that or just coding everything yourself? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp or https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/  or  https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am not using bootstrap, just plane old HTML and CSS. I have looked into the default progress-element and am able to get the progress bar. But what I am looking for is the same style as shown in the image. The default progress bar gives me a plane bar with a constant fill or gradient fill but not the fill as shown in the image. I tried using some css but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could find...

```
<style type="text/css">

#layer1 { -moz-animation-delay:0.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s; }
#layer2 { -moz-animation-delay:1s; -webkit-animation-delay:1s; }
#layer3 { -moz-animation-delay:1.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s; }
#layer4 { -moz-animation-delay:2s; -webkit-animation-delay:2s; }
#layer5 { -moz-animation-delay:2.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:2.5s; }

#layer7 { -moz-animation-delay:1.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s; }
#layer8 { -moz-animation-delay:2s; -webkit-animation-delay:2s; }
#layer9 { -moz-animation-delay:2.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:2.5s; }
#layer10 { -moz-animation-delay:3s; -webkit-animation-delay:3s; }
#layer11 { -moz-animation-delay:3.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:3.5s; }

@-moz-keyframes loading {
    0%{-moz-transform:scale(0,0);}
    100%{-moz-transform:scale(1,1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);}
}


@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0%   {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
    10%  {-moz-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.5;}
    50%  {-moz-transform: scale(1.75);opacity: 0;}
    100% {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
    10%  {-webkit-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.5;}
    50%  {-webkit-transform: scale(1.75);opacity: 0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
}

/* Loader Bar */

ul#loadbar {
    list-style:none;
    width:140px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:75px;
    margin-left: 530px;
}
ul#loadbar li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:11px;
    height:26px;
    margin-left:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #111; border-top:1px solid #111; border-right:1px solid #333; border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    background:#000;
}

ul#loadbar li:first-child { margin-left:0; }

.ins .bar {
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #7ec0ee 25%, #a0eaff);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #7ec0ee 25%, #a0eaff);
    width:11px;
    height:26px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fill .5s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation:fill .5s linear forwards;
}

#layerFill1 { -moz-animation-delay:0.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s; }
#layerFill2 { -moz-animation-delay:1s; -webkit-animation-delay:1s; }
#layerFill3 { -moz-animation-delay:1.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s; }
#layerFill4 { -moz-animation-delay:2s; -webkit-animation-delay:2s; }
#layerFill5 { -moz-animation-delay:2.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:2.5s; }
#layerFill6 { -moz-animation-delay:3s; -webkit-animation-delay:3s; }
#layerFill7 { -moz-animation-delay:3.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:3.5s; }
#layerFill8 { -moz-animation-delay:4s; -webkit-animation-delay:4s; }
#layerFill9 { -moz-animation-delay:4.5s; -webkit-animation-delay:4.5s; }
#layerFill10 { -moz-animation-delay:5s; -webkit-animation-delay:5s; }

@-moz-keyframes fill {
    0%{ opacity:0; }
    100%{ opacity:1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
    0%{ opacity:0; }
    100%{ opacity:1; }
}

/* Trigger button for javascript */

.trigger, .triggerFull, .triggerBar {
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%,#000000 100%);
    border-left:1px solid #111; border-top:1px solid #111; border-right:1px solid #333; border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 140px;
}



</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loadbar').removeClass('ins');
        $('.triggerBar').click(function() {
            $('#loadbar').removeClass('ins').delay(10).queue(function(next){
                $(this).addClass('ins');
                next();
            });
            return false;
        });
});
</script>

<div class="container">
    <ul id="loadbar">
    <li><div id="layerFill1" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill2" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill3" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill4" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill5" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill6" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill7" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill8" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill9" class="bar"></div></li>
    <li><div id="layerFill10" class="bar"></div></li>
    </ul>
<a class="triggerBar" href="#">Start/Restart Animation</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! This is exactly what I wanted. Works like a charm. Thanks AJ. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have google which would take less time to search for the answer..
https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/
or
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked into the default progress-element and am able to get the progress bar. But what I am looking for is the same style as shown in the image. The default progress bar gives me a plane bar with a constant fill or gradient fill but not the fill as shown in the image. I tried using some css but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.progress{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 15px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 1px 3px #222;
}
.container-fluid{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.vtext{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      
      
    <div style="background-image: url('bg2.png');background-repeat:repeat;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container col-md-3">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped  bg-success progress-bar-animated" style="width:50%">
              <span class="vtext">50 %</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="container col-md-3">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-danger progress-bar-animated" style="width:30%">
              <span class="vtext">30 %</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you accidentially posted a draft? Please add some explanation and / or make a fiddle.